# ¿Cuál es la forma más concisa de encontrar la palabra que contiene una cadena en un cadena más larga en Python?

Tags: python, string, revisión-de-código

Estoy usando esta forma, ¿Existe alguna forma más concisa para hacerlo en Python? (menos líneas, menos palabras)

```
    text = "hola me llamo Pablo" 

    text = text.split()
         for word in text:
               if "pa" in word:
                    print word

# El resultado deseado es Pablo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No creo que puedas simplificar mucho, pero si lo que quieres que de ese String te devuelva Pablo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
texto = "hola me llamo Pablo"
pos_la = texto.find('Pablo')
print texto[pos_la:]
```

Comment: Creo que el ejemplo que use no es el mejor, pero para el caso que di tu respuesta sirve, asi que te la acepto. se complica si "pa" esta en el medio de la palabra o si despues de Pablo hay mas texto, creo

Comment: Se complicaría, pero puedes cortar hasta donde quieres que imprima

Answer (score 5):

Tienes varias posibilidades si deseas buscar palabras (no simplemente subcadenas).

Tu ideas es correcta, puedes 'simplificarla' usando generadores y list comprehensions:

```
for r in (t for t in text.split() if 'Pa' in t):
   print r
```

ó:

```
for r in (t for t in text.split() if t.startswith('Pa')):
   print r
```

Otra opción es usar expresiones regulares:

```
import re

for math in re.finditer(r'\bPa\w*\b', text):
   print math.group()
```

En los dos últimos casos se crea un generador/iterador con todas las palabras del string que **empiezan** por 'Pa', en el primer caso incluye todas las palabras que **continenen** 'Pa' igual que tu código.

Si usas Python 3 (o usando la función `print` importandola de `__future__` en Python 2) puedes conseguir el mismo efecto en una linea:

```
print(*(t for t in text.split() if t.startswith('Pa')), sep='\n')
```

,

```
print(*(t for t in text.split() if 'Pa' in t), sep='\n')
```

y

```
import re

print(*re.findall(r'\bPa\w*\b', text), sep='\n')
```

En cuanto a eficiencia (en base a tiempo de ejecución), la mejor opción es `(t for t in text.split() if 'Pa' in t)`, seguida de las expresiones regulares, después tú código y el peor es usar el método `startwith`.

Si lo que quieres es encontrar las palabras que **empiezan** por una subcadena dada usa expresiones regulares sin duda, si lo que quieres es obtener todas las palabras que **contienen** una subcadena dada puedes usar el primer código o expresiones regulares también pero cambiando el patrón por:

```
r'\b\w*Pa\w*\b'
```

**Nota:** Si vas a usar expresiones regulares y usas la misma expresión para buscar muchas veces a lo largo de tu código, es más eficiente compilarla primero usando [re.compile()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile). Si solo la usas una vez no aporta nada.

Comment: respuesta muy completa!

Answer (score 2):

Usando expresiones regulares podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
import re

text = "Hola me llamo Pablo"
ts = "Pa" # lo que quieres buscar 
pat = re.compile("(\w*{0}\w*)".format(ts))
print(pat.findall(text)) # Imprime todas las palabras que contienen a ts
```

Lo anterior es bastante "mejorable", pero creo que, en principio, funciona.

Comment: Esto generaría errores si se usan metacaracteres sin escapar. Además, podría hacerse más eficiente con `\b`

Answer (score 1):

¿Que tál de la siguiente manera?

```
mystring = "hola me llamo Pablo"
word = "Pablo"

if word in mystring: 
   print word
```

Comment: Puede que sea una respuesta correcta pero no para la misma pregunta. A lo mejor no fui 100% claro pero si pones que word sea "pa" no funciona, devuelve "pa" y el resultado que necesito es que devuelva "pablo"

Comment: Eso es porque "pa" como tal no se encuentra en `mystring`. Se encuentra "Pa" con la P en mayúscula. Para tu caso podrías convertir la cadena a minúscula todo, y así poder comprobar si se encuentra.

Comment: Quise decir "Pa". Si pones "Pa" devuelve "Pa" y no Pablo que es el resultado deseado